# <script> not showing in HTML meta box text field

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have searched and can't find an answer for this but I am having real issues showing this below script on my new site I am trying to create:

```
<script src="https://widgets.bookalet.co.uk/publish.js" data-bookalet="8e3ce4a1-11c8-4295-b52f-0ebd0bc1849e" data-property="424" data-monthcount="3" data-theme="55"></script>
```

The script shows a booking calendar which is provided by a third party company. I can display the script via the normal text box at the top of the wordpress page but it will not show via the meta box.

Please see images for more info.

[Image 1 shows code in Text Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83KHw.png)

[Image 2 Shows as a video File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziccA.png)

I am not sure if this is a theme issue or wordpress security thing?

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Read this i this can help you [here https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript)

**JavaScript in Posts**
To use JavaScript inside of posts in WordPress, you need to take a few more steps. Odds are that this usage is for one or only a few instances, so adding the script to the header would only add code you don't need to your header.php template file.

For the occassional or one time use of JavaScript, you need to put the script into a JavaScript file and then call it out from within the post. Make sure that each script is defined by its function name such as:

```
function updatepage(){var m="Page updated "+document.lastMo.......}
```

To include a JavaScript inside a post, you need to combine both the call to the script file with the call to the JavaScript itself.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/updatepage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
updatepage();
//--></script>
```